# Unable to access jarfile server.jar

Tags: terminal, mac, java

I am trying to add ram to my Minecraft server. To do this I have created a start.command file with the following text in it:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd “$(dirname “$0”)”
exec java -Xms4G -Xmx4G -jar server.jar
```

I have run this terminal command on the start command file:

```
chmod a+x /Users/hutonahill/Desktop/server\ files/start.command
```

But when I run the start.command (by double-clicking it in finder) I get an error:
Unable to access jarfile server.jar" Googleing has reviled that most of the time this error steems from the start.command file and the server.jar file not being in the same location, or server.jar being spelled wrong in the start.command file.

I have ruled out both of these possibilities. I have copied and pasted the name server.jar into the start.command file and I know that they are both in the same file.

Help!

PS. I am running Mac OSX 0.14.6 and java 8 update 251

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem! on line 2 of start.command I was using [”] instead of ["].  mac OS likes to replace normal quotation marks with these when you copy/past them. java does not see [”] as a quotation mark, so you have to manually enter the quotation marks with your keyboard.